# Can't fill the array that is a member of a class. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, fill

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
public:
    bool someArray[4][4]={{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}};
};

int main()
{
     SomeClass super;
     super.someArray={{1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1}};  //This goes red, indicates a mistake. How do i properly fill it?

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
           cout<<super.someArray[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Please see the comments in the code above.
By the way:  `super.someArray[4][4]={{1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1}};` doesn't work either and it probably shouldn't.

Comment: By "this goes red", what do you mean?

Comment: well i mean, that the IDE (Qt Creator) indicates an error. When i try to compile it it says: assigning to an array from an initializer list.

Comment: There appears to be a second error (the other array initialization).  If you comment out the one indicated red line, does the code compile and run?

Comment: Yes, compiles and runs smoothly.

Comment: I think neither initialization is valid in old C++.  The second initialization should work if you have a compiler that supports C++11.  One reason the first one is invalid is because you can't initialize member data at its point of declaration unless it is "static const".  Non-const member data should be initialized in constructors.

Answer (score 2):

1. You probably mean to use `bool someArray[2][4]` (i.e, an array with two elements that contains arrays with four boolean elements).
2. You can't assign one array into another in C++; you'll need to copy the individual elements.  I.e., something like:

   super.someArray[0][0] = 1;
   super.someArray[0][1] = 1;
   super.someArray[0][2] = 1;
   super.someArray[0][3] = 0;
   super.someArray[1][0] = 1;
   super.someArray[1][1] = 0;
   super.someArray[1][2] = 0;
   super.someArray[1][3] = 1;

(If you have some source for your data, you could use a loop of course.)

Comment: Even if he doesn't have a source for the data, he can create one (a local array), thus making the code much more readable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Agreed.  Of course, the someArray variable should probably be getting initialized in a constructor while he's at it.

Comment: You can use an initialization in C or C++, but it must be part of the delclaration. int myarray[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}; is valid, for example.

Comment: Could you please tell more about it? About how to create a local source of data, or maybe where i can read about it? Actually the best would be if it would get the data from an external text file for example.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me using the GNU compiler.  Notice that I replaced your raw array with std::tr1::array.  This class is more flexible with respect to assigning entire arrays (as opposed to just initializing arrays from literals).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/array>
using namespace std;
using namespace tr1;
typedef array<array<bool,4>,4> array4x4;

class SomeClass {
public:
    array4x4 someArray;
    SomeClass() : someArray((array4x4){{{{0,0,0,0}},{{0,0,0,0}}}}) {}
};

int main()
{
     SomeClass super;
     super.someArray=(array4x4){{{{1,1,1,0}},{{1,0,0,1}}}};  //Now works

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
           cout<<super.someArray[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

However, the following approach is a bit closer to where you started, and demonstrates some of the things suggested in other comments...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
public:
    bool someArray[4][4];
    SomeClass()
       {
       bool temp[4][4] = {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}};
       for ( int j=0; j<4; j++ ) for ( int i=0; i<4; i++ ) someArray[j][i] = temp[j][i];
       }
};

int main()
{
     SomeClass super;
       bool temp[4][4] = {{1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1}}; // a local source of data
       for ( int j=0; j<4; j++ ) for ( int i=0; i<4; i++ ) super.someArray[j][i] = temp[j][i];

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
           cout<<super.someArray[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, notice the double bracketing {{}} used to initialize std::tr1::array. I don't know what this is called, but it seems to be required in order to make this kind of initialization (at least with some compilers). I also don't know that this syntax is standard-compliant.

Comment: by the new standart, double bracketing is not needed. only non-conforming compilers need that.

Comment: The second approach is standard-compliant and easy to understand, but I think it is quite a bit more error-prone.  There are multiple places where you could crash the program by using the wrong value for an array size.

Answer (score 1):

```
super.someArray[4][4]={{1,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1}};
```

The line above just needs to be:

```
super.someArray[4][4]={1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1};
```

**Explaination:**
it will automatically go the next section of the array. If you think of it as a table, once the first row is filled up, it will start declaring it for the next row.

So if you wrote:

```
super.someArray[4][4]={1,1,1,1,1};
```

it would set:

```
someArray[0][0] 
someArray[0][1] 
someArray[0][2] 
someArray[0][3] 
someArray[1][0]
```

all equal to 1.

(I might have the numbers switched so it could be x and y places are changed, I can't recall for c++)